# Client to close the connection

Tags: java, sockets

I got a socket listener which keep listening for data. The problem now is that the client which send data will finally close the connection by itself. Based on my codes below I am wondering do I still need to perform this part of the codes where it does `writeBuffer.close();`?

Should I remove the final part and just put the socket closing the catch?

```
public void run()
{   
     BufferedWriter writeBuffer = null;
     BufferedReader readBuffer = null;

     String message="";
     try {
         writeBuffer =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream()));
         readBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));

         int m = 0, count=0;
         int nextChar=0;         

         while ((nextChar=readBuffer.read()) != -1) 
         {
          message += (char) nextChar;  
          if (nextChar == '#')
          {
              System.out.println("\n\nSending PA : "+message);
                  writeBuffer.write("$PA\r\n");
              writeBuffer.flush(); 
              message="";               
              }
         }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)  
    { 
        System.out.println("MyError:Exception has been caught in in the main first try");
    ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }   
    /*finally
    {
        try 
        {
            if ( writeBuffer != null ) 
        {
            writeBuffer.close();
        }
            else 
        {
                System.out.println("MyError:writeBuffer is null in finally close");
        }
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Crossposted to Oracle Java forums: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2314932&tstart=0.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to explicitly close the connections you're using. Think about it, it might be possible that the client never closes the connection (of course, then you'd have to implement some kind of timeout mechanism that closes the connection on the server side after a certain amount of time, but that's a different matter).

My point is - it never hurts to be careful, and manage your resources in a conservative fashion.

Comment: So what changes should I make to my codes further? Based on your experience in my scenario where the client supposedly will be closing the connection what should I do? The problem my codes run fine for most of the times but suddenly I find some garbage at times and that is towards the end of the connection.

Comment: You could define a special message from the client, say "exit", in such a way that when you receive it, you exit the loop and let the `finally` block close the connection.

Comment: The problem the client is a gps device. How it operate is that after it send all the data then 15sec later it will close the connection with the server. Do you think the corruption could be server close the connection earlier then the client?

Comment: I don't know, in your code, the only way that the `while` exits is if it receives a value of `-1`, which typically happens when the client closes first the connection. Try removing the part in the `finally` block and see if it still gets closed after 15 seconds

Comment: How to confirm that the client have close the connection? Is via monitoring the traffic or can I do it via the java codes itself? Must I keep running netstat -a?

Comment: Give it a test, start the server, start the client and connect it to the client, and then close the client (perhaps turning off the gps?), look at what happens in the server: my guess is that the connection is closed, you don't have to monitor it

Comment: That is my problem what indication can I get to say the client is closing the connection or the connection already been closed properly by the client? Or are you trying to tell me to look out for some error message if there is problem is it?

Comment: Test your code, see what happens after the client closes - does it continue after the `while` ? does it enter the `catch` block? either way, the `finally` block gets executed and the server closes the connection

Comment: Ok I have updated my codes here where I commented the final section, change the catch IOException to Exception. So I dont notice it goes into the catch section. I notice it keep sending data just as usual? So should I maintain this as my permanent code?

Comment: If now the connection doesn't get closed after 15 seconds, you should leave the code like this, but be sure to somehow close the connection when you're sure that the client is disconnected - and it's up to you how to do it

Comment: I am a bit lost here. IF this is the scenario how to confirm that after 15 sec actually the connection is closed on the client side? Is there where I can verified the close is coming from the client be sure the whole socket is closed?

Comment: @user1056561 The client has closed the connection when read() returns -1. You've been told that before in other places.

Comment: @EJP Several times, as a matter of fact :) . user1056561 : Test your own code, I've answered enough of your questions.

Comment: I notice the connection is still established and at times I see it in close_wait too? So that is what confusing me if read() already return -1 why is the connection still at Established or Close_Wait status? I was wondering to open up the finally block and wait for 20 sec and check if the socket is still not close then force close? Is that a better idea?